# Returning Unique IDs from Oracle Update statement in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am trying to update a selection of rows in an Oracle table we are using to handle messages.  Because this table is busy, it would be best if the update could return the UniqueIDs of the rows it updated in an atomic transaction.  I modified a code sample I found on StackOverflow to look like the following, but when I examine the parameter "p", I don't find any information coming back from the update statement, as I expected.

Any suggestions for modifying either the .NET code that is setting up the Oracle call, or modifying the Oracle SQL statement itself?

```
        Dim connectString As String = data source=ORA1;user id=MESSAGEBOX;password=MESSAGEBOX

    Dim conn As New OracleConnection(connectString)
    If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        conn.Open()
    End If
    Dim transaction As OracleTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction()

    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand()
    cmd.Connection = conn

    cmd.CommandText = "BEGIN UPDATE MESSAGE_TABLE SET C_WAS_PROCESSED = 2 WHERE C_ID IN (SELECT * FROM(SELECT C_ID FROM MESSAGE_TABLE WHERE C_WAS_PROCESSED = 0 AND  C_CREATED_DATE_TIME < CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE)  ORDER BY C_MESSAGE_PRIORITY, C_ID) WHERE ROWNUM < 16)  RETURNING C_ID BULK COLLECT INTO :C_ID; END;"


    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    cmd.BindByName = True
    cmd.ArrayBindCount = 15

    Dim p As New OracleParameter()
    p.ParameterName = "C_ID"
    p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    p.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64
    p.Size = 15
    p.ArrayBindSize = New Integer() {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10}
    p.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p)

    Dim nRowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    transaction.Commit()
    conn.Close()
    conn.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that problem here is that SQL variable being `RETURNED BULK COLLECT INTO` needs to be of a TABLE type, not a simple number type.

Alter your SQL to include a declaration block like follows:

```
cmd.CommandText = "DECLARE TYPE IDS IS TABLE OF MESSAGE_TABLE.C_ID%TYPE; C_ID IDS; 
BEGIN UPDATE MESSAGE_TABLE SET C_WAS_PROCESSED = 2 WHERE C_ID IN (SELECT * FROM(SELECT C_ID FROM MESSAGE_TABLE WHERE C_WAS_PROCESSED = 0 AND  C_CREATED_DATE_TIME < CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE)  ORDER BY C_MESSAGE_PRIORITY, C_ID) WHERE ROWNUM < 16)  RETURNING C_ID BULK COLLECT INTO :C_ID; END;"
```

I got the table declaration syntax from this [oracle-base.com](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause#collections) link.

Comment: This works:

`DECLARE
  TYPE tReturn IS TABLE OF COR_INBOX_ENTRY.C_ID%TYPE;
   M_ID tReturn;
  BEGIN
  UPDATE COR_INBOX_ENTRY SET C_WAS_PROCESSED = 2 
  RETURNING C_ID BULK COLLECT INTO :M_ID; 
  END;`
But this does not

`UPDATE COR_INBOX_ENTRY SET C_WAS_PROCESSED = 2 WHERE C_ID > 0 AND C_WAS_PROCESSED = 0 RETURNING C_ID BULK COLLECT INTO :M_ID`

Apparently, if the value you are updating is part of the WHERE clause, ODP.NET doesn't seem to handle returning anything.